# Comparison of geocoding solutions (such as Gisgraphy & PostGIS 2.0)

Tags: postgis, geocoding, reverse-geocoding, postgis-2.0, gisgraphy

As I am sure many of you are aware, PostGIS has finally released Version 2.0 and included within this version they have also built a geocoder (see: http://postgis.net/docs/Extras.html).

Although I realize V2 was just released I am curious to know if anyone has had the opportunity to compare other opensource solutions such as gisgraphy.com.

I personally am interested in understanding the differences in terms of speed, features/options, accuracy, and the ease of being able to use ones own dataset(s).

Answer (score 3):

Another geocoder to consider is Nominatim. It uses OpenStreetMap data.

http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Nominatim

For the usage policy of nominatim.openstreetmap.org, please see [Nominatim usage policy](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Nominatim_usage_policy).
MapQuest also provide [a version of this API](http://open.mapquestapi.com/nominatim/), without the usage limits.

As for comparisons... I have not come across much in terms of benchmarks or a feature matrix to compare geocoding options. Though these links may help give you some addi

[Geocoding API's Compared](http://philsturgeon.co.uk/blog/2011/02/geocoding-apis-compared)

[7 Free Geocoding APIs](http://blog.programmableweb.com/2012/06/21/7-free-geocoding-apis-google-bing-yahoo-and-mapquest/)

[Geocoder-Comparison](https://github.com/eyeseast/geocoder-comparison)