# Logic behind Google querying based on POI

Tags: geocoding, google-maps-api, latitude-longitude

I am Currently Working in Geocoding process based on google API service.Today my superior asked a question how does Google exactly query a POI(Place Of Interest) if it is latitude and Longitude is passed.Can anyone help me in answering this?

Comment: Are you asking how geocoding works in general, or details of how the Google geocoding implementation works?

Comment: @BradHards Google geocoding implementation works?

Comment: This depends on where in the world you are querying, some countries only have city/town level geocoding and others have actual building rooftop accuracy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no realistic way that you can provide information to your supervisor (superior has other connotations) on how Google implemented the service behind their geocoding API. Google, in general, is not very forthcoming on technical implementation details for their services, because it represents competitive advantage. Note: this isn't to say that there are not exceptions including open source projects / products, but geocoding is not one of those exceptions.

You can make reasonable assumptions based on other geocoding implementations (see [Comparison of geocoding solutions (such as Gisgraphy & PostGIS 2.0)](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/23113/comparison-of-geocoding-solutions-such-as-gisgraphy-postgis-2-0) or similar questions on this site), and looking at some of the more recent / aggressive projects such as [CLAVIN](https://github.com/Berico-Technologies/CLAVIN) might also provide insight. However these are assumptions, not facts.